# How to add link to a device permanently

Tags: centos, symlink, udev

Using the command: `ln -s /dev/ttyUSB0 /dev/gps0` I link the device `gps0` to `ttyUSB0`. The problem is after rebooting the machine, the created link will disappear and I should create it again. Is there any way to create the link permanently?

The OS is CentOS 7.

Answer (score 2):

Given the name of your device --- `/dev/gps0` --- I assume that you're dealing with some sort of GPS device.  If so, your best bet would be to define a custom `udev` rule that matches the device and creates a device with the name that you want.  [Arch Linux's udev wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udev) might help to get you started; I don't think there will be fundamental differences between that and CentOS.

Comment: Thanks, I read about the `udev`. Could you pls give me an example?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a Linux machine in front of me.  Did you see the wiki to which I referred you?  The bit that talks about `83-webcam.rules` is very similar to what you're after.  You'll want to use `udevadm` to find out properties of your GPS (e.g., vendor, product id), and create a rule that generates the symlink.

Answer (score 0):

Add it /etc/rc.local. Make sure /etc/rc.local is executable.

```
vim /etc/rc.local
ln -s /dev/ttyUSB0 /dev/gps0

ls -l /etc/rc.local 
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 13 Sep 26 05:46 /etc/rc.local -> rc.d/rc.local
```

Comment: I did but after reboot, it didn't create the link. Maybe because the command needs `sudo` privileges